# How to get a response from a javascript post request

Tags: javascript, post, request

So I'm using this post request I found on here, but I'm wondering how I receive a response using this...

```
function post_to_url(path, params, method) {
    method = method || "post"; 
    var form = document.createElement("form");
    form.setAttribute("method", method);
    form.setAttribute("action", path);

    for(var key in params) {
        if(params.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");
            hiddenField.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
            hiddenField.setAttribute("name", key);
            hiddenField.setAttribute("value", params[key]);

            form.appendChild(hiddenField);
         }
    }ody.appendChild(form);
    form.submit();
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have a look at AJAX. It's better for your purpose than submitting a form.

Answer (score 1):

This code configures a form and submits it. You don't get any response to javascript, because the page reloads.

Try using jQuery: 
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Or plain javascript AJAX: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/AJAX if you want to write the whole thing yourself